# Is a kind of TypeDescriptor or RouteValueDictionary available in portable class library?

Tags: portable-class-library

I'm searching for a way to pass an argument which value is a dictionary constructed from an object: `MyMethod(new { param1="public", param2=123 })`.

Using RouteValueDictionary we can easily convert the object into an IDictionary. But RouteValueDictionary requires TypeDescriptor which is not available in PCL.

Is there an another way to do it ?

==== EDIT ====

Found a working code for profile 104:

```
void MyMethod(object oParams)
{
    var dic = from property in oParams.GetType().GetProperties()
              select new KeyValuePair<string,object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(oParams,null));
    ...
}
```